# ListView adapter returns wrong items

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a survey with 2 types of answers:

1)Open (checkbox or radio button) + (user may input text)
2)Ordinary (checkbox or radio button)

When I have a large list like 20+ elements ListView shows wrong type of answer.

I guess that the problem is with getItem(), because the type of the answer depends on it's data.

I have tried many ways to resolve the problem, could not even mention all stackoverflow links.
Maybe, somebody may help me.

```
public class AnswerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Answer> {

public interface ActionsListener {
    void onCheckClicked(View v, Answer answer, int position);

    void onRadioClicked(View v, Answer answer, int position);

    void onOpenClicked(View v, Answer answer, int position);
}

private Display mDisplay;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context mContext;
private ActionsListener mActionsListener;
private String language;
private ArrayList<Answer> mList;


public AnswerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Answer> list, String language, ActionsListener actionsListener) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_answer, list);
    mList = list;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
    mActionsListener = actionsListener;
    this.language = language;
    mDisplay = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Answer getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(this.getPosition(mList.get(position)));
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View row = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_answer, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.answerTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_title);
        holder.answerRadio = (AppCompatRadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_radio);
        holder.answerCheck = (AppCompatCheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_check);
        holder.answerPicture = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_picture);
        holder.answerOpen = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_open);
        holder.answerRank = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_rank);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    final Answer answer = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder viewHolderFinal = holder;

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.answer_check:
                    mActionsListener.onCheckClicked(v, answer, position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case R.id.answer_radio:
                    mActionsListener.onRadioClicked(v, answer, position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case R.id.answer_title:
                case R.id.answer_picture:
                    if (viewHolderFinal.answerCheck.isEnabled() && viewHolderFinal.answerRadio.isEnabled())
                        if (answer.getPolyAnswer()) {
                            viewHolderFinal.answerCheck.setChecked(!viewHolderFinal.answerCheck.isChecked());
                            onClick(viewHolderFinal.answerCheck);
                        } else {
                            viewHolderFinal.answerRadio.setChecked(true);
                            onClick(viewHolderFinal.answerRadio);
                        }
                    break;
                case R.id.answer_open:

                    mActionsListener.onOpenClicked(v, answer, position);

                    if (viewHolderFinal.answerCheck.isEnabled() && viewHolderFinal.answerRadio.isEnabled()) {
                        if (answer.getPolyAnswer()) {
                            onClick(viewHolderFinal.answerCheck);
                        } else {
                            onClick(viewHolderFinal.answerRadio);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    holder.answerTitle.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    holder.answerPicture.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    holder.answerOpen.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    holder.answerOpen.setHint(language); //language[6]

    holder.answerTitle.setText(answer.getTitle());
    holder.answerTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorUIWhite));

    if (answer.getPolyAnswer()) {
        holder.answerCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.answerCheck.setChecked(answer.getCheck());
        holder.answerCheck.setEnabled(answer.getEnabled());
        holder.answerCheck.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    } else {
        holder.answerRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.answerRadio.setChecked(answer.getCheck());
        holder.answerRadio.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }


    if (answer.getIsOpenAnswer()) {
        holder.answerOpen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.answerOpen.setText(answer.getOpenAnswer());
        holder.answerOpen.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorUIWhite));
        holder.answerOpen.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorUIWhite));
        holder.answerOpen.setError(answer.getOpenAnswerError());
    }

    return row;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView answerTitle;
    AppCompatRadioButton answerRadio;
    AppCompatCheckBox answerCheck;
    ImageView answerPicture;
    EditText answerOpen;
    Button answerRank;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your `getView()` method, I'd assume you also end up with situations where both your radio and check show as visible at the same time as well.

Because `getView()` can recycle the view (when convertView is not null), any showing elements retain their visibility.

So you should add an else to your `answer.getIsOpenAnswer()` where when it is not you set answerOpen's visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE (depending on your design).

In your if statement for answer.getPolyAnswer() you need to probably set answerRadio to INVISIBLE or GONE and answerCheck to INVISIBLE or GONE in your else as well.

Comment: Consider formatting your answer like put this `` to make the letters as code like `getView();` just for readability.

Comment: The solution is so easy! I have never had problems with radio or check but the problem with open was solved by adding else statement. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah good bro, congratulations its accepted. My upvote was worth it. **Happy Coding!**.